# De-mean the data and convert to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I am trying to implement basic Matrix Factorization movie Recommender system on Movielens 1M dataset. But I am stuck here. what I want to do is  I need to do is de-mean the data (normalize by each users mean) and convert it from a dataframe to a numpy array.

Code Snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ratings_list = [i.strip().split("::") for i in open('S:/TIP/ml-1m/ratings.dat', 'r').readlines()]
#users_list = [i.strip().split("::") for i in open('/users/nickbecker/Downloads/ml-1m/users.dat', 'r').readlines()]
movies_list = [i.strip().split("::") for i in open('S:/TIP/ml-1m/movies.dat', 'r').readlines()]

ratings_df = pd.DataFrame(ratings_list, columns = ['UserID', 'MovieID', 'Rating', 'Timestamp'], dtype = int)
movies_df = pd.DataFrame(movies_list, columns = ['MovieID', 'Title', 'Genres'])
movies_df['MovieID'] = movies_df['MovieID'].apply(pd.to_numeric)


R_df = ratings_df.pivot(index = 'UserID', columns ='MovieID', values = 'Rating').fillna(0)
R_df.head()

R = R_df.to_numpy()
user_ratings_mean = np.mean(R, axis = 1)
R_demeaned = R - user_ratings_mean.reshape(-1, 1)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\TIP\Code\MF_orig.py", line 17, in <module>
    user_ratings_mean = np.mean(R, axis = 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in mean
  File "C:\Users\sarda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3257, in mean
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 151, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Edit:
Value of R is:

```
[['5' 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ['5' 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 ['4' 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

ratings_df:

```
        UserID MovieID Rating  Timestamp
0            1    1193      5  978300760
1            1     661      3  978302109
2            1     914      3  978301968
3            1    3408      4  978300275
4            1    2355      5  978824291
...        ...     ...    ...        ...
1000204   6040    1091      1  956716541
1000205   6040    1094      5  956704887
1000206   6040     562      5  956704746
1000207   6040    1096      4  956715648
1000208   6040    1097      4  956715569
```

movies_df:

```
      MovieID                               Title                        Genres
0           1                    Toy Story (1995)   Animation|Children's|Comedy
1           2                      Jumanji (1995)  Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
2           3             Grumpier Old Men (1995)                Comedy|Romance
3           4            Waiting to Exhale (1995)                  Comedy|Drama
4           5  Father of the Bride Part II (1995)                        Comedy
...       ...                                 ...                           ...
3878     3948             Meet the Parents (2000)                        Comedy
3879     3949          Requiem for a Dream (2000)                         Drama
3880     3950                    Tigerland (2000)                         Drama
3881     3951             Two Family House (2000)                         Drama
3882     3952               Contender, The (2000)                Drama|Thriller

[3883 rows x 3 columns]
```

Dataset link:
http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-1m.zip

Comment: can you post here what R is?

Comment: @Vicrobot I have posted the value of R. For the code bit the initialization is there in code bit above

Comment: Seems like it contains string instances. That may be the reason for error. Filter the dataframe before converting to numpy.

Comment: @Vicrobot I there seeemed to be no string instances. Infact the data is already standardized research data from movielens.com a research initiative by University of Minnesota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working on object and even giving the dtype argument to pandas dataframe constructor isn't converting that to integer.

You have to convert it to int explicitly:

```
ratings_list = [[int(j) for j in i.strip().split("::") if j] for i in open('ratings.txt', 'r').readlines()]
```

And then proceed. I tried and this works.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot for the answer. it works but there is one more thing which i observed, while using another approach. I found that the data type was integer before using to_numpy and after using to_numpy() the data type became string. which is weird and I cant figure out why.

Comment: @ShivamSarda it shouldn't happen. NumPy isn't going to do such stuff secretively. There must be some third action done from your side. You might be thinking it's integer probably because of seeing how it gets printed out but it might be string the whole time.